# Append values in regular expressions

Tags: regex, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using Xpath and regular expressions to obtain data from a web page
I'm using the following xpath to get the portion I'm interested in.

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="business-detail"]/div/p').extract()
```

EDIT:
Which provides the following:

```
[u'<p><span class="business-phone" itemprop="telephone">(415) 287-4225</span><span class="business-address" itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress"><span itemprop="streetAddress">2180 Bryant St. STE 203, </span><span itemprop="addressLocality">San Francisco</span>,\xa0<span itemprop="addressRegion">CA</span>\xa0<span itemprop="postalCode">94110</span></span><span class="business-link"><a href="http://www.klopfarchitecture.com" rel="nofollow" lang="LS30TPCERNYc3ad1e44689537236560bc0b17983458&amp;GAQ0FURUdPUlk6QnVzaW5lc3MgUmV2aWV3IFJlZmVycmFsc35VUkwgQ2xpY2t+d3d3Lmtsb3BmYXJjaGl0ZWN0dXJlLmNvbX4xNTI4MDU=" itemprop="url">www.klopfarchitecture.com</a></span> <br><br></p>']
```

I'm interested in

```
<span itemprop="streetAddress">2180 Bryant St. STE 203, </span>

<span itemprop="addressLocality">San Francisco</span>

<span itemprop="addressRegion">CA</span>
<span itemprop="postalCode">94110</span>
```

So I'm using this regex to extract the data

```
reg = r'"streetAddress">[0-9]+[^<]*'

reg = r'"addressLocality"[^<]*'

reg = r'"addressRegion"[^<]*'

reg = r'"postalCode"[^<]*'
```

The problem is that are four of them so I get four variables, I need to append the data to have the full address in one variable to assign it to an Item, what would be an efficient way to accomplish it?

EDIT2:

You're right Roshan Jossey, I can use  response.xpath('//*[@itemprop="streetAddress"]').extract()
But still are four labels, addressLocality, addressRegion and postal code. how I merge the results?

I looking for this result:

2180 Bryant St. STE 203, San Francisco, CA 94110

And I'm getting this format for each of the four parts

```
<span itemprop="streetAddress">2180 Bryant St. STE 203, </span>
```

Comment: Have you tried with just xpath, like response.xpath('//*[@id="business-detail"]/div/p/span[@itemprop="streetAddress"]/text()').extract() and so on?

Comment: I have try the xpath in wich is the direction:
response.xpath('//*[@id="business-detail"]/div/p/span[2]/span[1]').extract()
The problem is that is not exactly in the same places in all the pages, so I took a bigger piece and start seaching with regex

Comment: How about trying with span[@itemprop="streetAddress"]‌​ rather than just span[1]?  Or is that span not a direct child of p node?. could you share that part of html too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to use just xpaths to solve this problem

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="business-detail"]/div/p//span[@itemprop="streetAddress"]/text()').extract()[0]
```

will provide you the street address. You can extract all other elements in a similar fashion. Then its just a matter of concatenating them.
Regular expressions looks like an overkill when such simple xpath solutions exist.